# python - Steganography - UnicodeDecode Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, steganography

I am writing a Python script to hide data in an image. It basically hides the bits in the last two bits of the red color in RGB map of each pixel in a .PNG. The script works fine for lowercase letters but produces an error with a full stop. It produces this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "E:\Python\Steganography\main.py", line 65, in 
>       print(unhide('coded-img.png'))   File "E:\Python\Steganography\main.py", line 60, in unhide
>       message = bin2str(binary)   File "E:\Python\Steganography\main.py", line 16, in bin2str
>       return n.to_bytes((n.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big').decode() UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position
>   6: invalid start byte

Here, is my code:

```
from PIL import Image

def str2bin(message):
    binary = bin(int.from_bytes(message.encode('utf-8'), 'big'))
    return binary[2:]

def bin2str(binary):
    n = int(binary, 2)
    return n.to_bytes((n.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big').decode()

def hide(filename, message):
    image = Image.open(filename)
    binary = str2bin(message) + '00000000'

    data = list(image.getdata())

    newData = []

    index = 0
    for pixel in data:
        if index < len(binary):
            pixel = list(pixel)
            pixel[0] >>= 2
            pixel[0] <<= 2
            pixel[0] += int('0b' + binary[index:index+2], 2)
            pixel = tuple(pixel)
            index += 2

        newData.append(pixel)

    print(binary)

    image.putdata(newData)
    image.save('coded-'+filename, 'PNG')

def unhide(filename):
    image = Image.open(filename)
    data = image.getdata()

    binary = '0'

    index = 0

    while binary[-8:] != '00000000':
        binary += bin(data[index][0])[-2:]
        index += 1

    binary = binary[:-1]

    print(binary)
    print(index*2)

    message = bin2str(binary)
    return message


hide('img.png', 'alpha.')
print(unhide('coded-img.png'))
```

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two problems with your code.

The first problem is that your encoding can be misaligned by 1 bit since leading null bits are not included in the output of the `bin()` function:

```
>>> bin(int.from_bytes('a'.encode('utf-8'), 'big'))[2:]
'1100001'
# This string is of odd length and (when joined with the terminating '00000000')
# turns into a still odd-length '110000100000000' which is then handled by your
# code as if there was an extra trailing zero (so that the length is even).
# During decoding you compensate for that effect with the
#
#       binary = binary[:-1]
#
# line. The latter is responsible for your stated problem when the binary
# representation of your string is in fact of even length and doesn't need
# the extra bit as in the below example:
>>> bin(int.from_bytes('.'.encode('utf-8'), 'big'))[2:]
'101110'
```

You better complement your binary string  to even length by prepending an extra null bit (if needed).

The other problem is that while restoring the hidden message the stopping condition `binary[-8:] == '00000000'` can be prematurely satisfied through leading bits of one (partially restored) symbol being concatenated to trailing bits of another symbol. This can happen, for example, in the following cases

- the symbol <kbd>@</kbd> (with ASCII code=64, i.e. 6 low order bits unset) followed by any character having an ASCII code value less than 64 (i.e. with 2 highest order bits unset);
- a space character (with ASCII code=32, i.e. 4 low order bits unset) followed by a linefeed/newline character(with ASCII code=10, i.e. 4 high order bits unset).

You can fix that bug by requiring that a full byte is decoded at the time when the last 8 bits appear to all be unset:

```
while not (len(binary) % 8 == 0 and binary[-8:] == '00000000'):
    # ...
```

Comment: Many, many thanks. Especially, the second tip, I had completely looked over it and it would have caused many errors in the future. Thanks.